# For an unbounded operator A, when is $D(A^{-1}) = D(A)'$? Is there a canonical isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

I am reading a text at the moment and I am not sure what the authors mean by $D(A^{-1})$.
In this situation $A: D(A) \subset H \longrightarrow H$ is an unbounded operator on a hilbert space $H$ which is also positive selfadjoint.
It has an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{e_k\}$ with eigenvectors $\{\lambda_k\}$.
The domain $D(A)$ is, as far as I can tell, equipped with the graph norm.

Now I would by default say that the domain of the inverse operator is then:
$$D(A^{-1}) = \left\{x \in H: \sum_{k}^\infty \lambda^{-k} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k \in H\right\}.$$
They seem to use $D(A^{-1})$ in a dual sense however, explicitly writing
$$D(A) \subset H = H' \subset D(A^{-1}).$$
I can see that there is a natural embedding
$$D(A^{-1}) \rightarrow D(A)'$$
by using the Riesz representation isomorphism. Then for $x \in D(A^{-1})$ and $y \in D(A)$:
$$ |\langle x, y\rangle| = |\langle A A^{-1}x, y \rangle| = |\langle A^{-1}, Ay \rangle| \leq \|A^{-1} x\|_H \|y\|_{D(A)}. $$
But I do not see why this would be surjective.

The authors also explicitly apply $A^{-1}$ to elements of $D(A^{-1})$ and get something in $H$. If the authors just used the notation $D(A^{-1})$ for $D(A)'$ then it is not clear to me what operator $A^{-1}$ represents on dual objects.

Could someone with more experience in functional analysis figure out how this is to be understood?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe a small coment: $A$ is a differnetial operator and since for Sobolev spaces the notation $H^{-\alpha} = (H^\alpha)'$ is common I thought that $D(A^{-1})$ has to be interpreted in a dual sense.